# NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)?

Tags: curl, openssl, centos, libcurl, centos6

I'm trying to access a third-party service via PHP curl on a Centos 6 system which comes with curl and libcurl compiled against NSS instead of OpenSSL.

This is causing problems for me, every time I try to access the service I get this error `NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)`.

My understanding is that I need to install the certificates in the NSS database.

I'm looking for step by step instructions on how to do this (keep in mind, I need this to work with PHP curl functions called from Nginx server)

Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Try prefixing the certificate filename with "./", or using the full path.  From the curl manpage:

> If  curl  is  built against the NSS SSL library then this option [--cert]
>       can tell curl the nickname of the certificate to use within  the
>       NSS  database defined by the environment variable SSL_DIR (or by
>       default /etc/pki/nssdb). If the NSS  PEM  PKCS#11  module  (lib-
>       nsspem.so)  is  available  then  PEM files may be loaded. **If you
>       want to use a file from the current directory, please precede it
>       with "./" prefix, in order to avoid confusion with a nickname.**

(emphasis mine)

Alternatively, some instructions for importing into the NSS certificate database are here, although I have not used them:
http://rcritten.fedorapeople.org/nss_compat_ossl.html

Comment: it doesnt worked for me... my curl isn´t compiled with nsspem. So I´m using nss database... but curl never find my key friendlyname. Even if I manage to list the key names with certutil...

Comment: This did not work for me, but lead me in the correct direction.  My CURL was compiled with NSS (checked with curl -version) - and this post is the solution that ended up working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265100/curl-command-unable-to-load-client-cert-8018/20140138#20140138

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on Centos 7. After debugging it was related to the the timeout.

So if you see this issue and use `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 300);`
Then check how long it takes. If it is around your timeout period. That is the problem and not related to any certificate.

I was expecting some timeout error from Curl in case of timeout but that doesn't seem to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message with curl when I entered the wrong password when trying to access a FTPS server which used simple password authentication. It had nothing to do with certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this error (Centos 7, PHP 7.1.33) by editing the openssl section of /etc/php.ini and adding direction to the openssl certificates:
openssl.cafile=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

Comment: For a stronger answer, try including more detail and formatting your text in a more readable way, @Josaph.