# curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178

Tags: curl, ssl, client-server

I am facing an SSL issue with the `curl`command. I want to reach an URL using my SSL client certificate and private key.

This is my command:

```
$ curl -k -v "https://myurl.com/" --cert ./certificate.pem --key ./private.key

* About to connect() to xx.xx.xx.xx port 23444 (#0)
*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx... connected
* Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 23444 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* warning: ignoring value of ssl.verifyhost
* Unable to load client key -8178.
* NSS error -8178
* Closing connection #0
curl: (58) Unable to load client key -8178.
```

The key is password protected, `curl` is not asking me to enter the password, which is very strange. Even if I pass the password with `--pass`, I still get the same error.

It seems that the argument `--key` is not considered, because If I replaced with `foo.key`, which doesn't exist on my filesystem, I still get the same error.

However, If use:

```
$ wget --certificate=./certificate.pem --private-key=private.key "https://myurl.com/" --no-check-certificate
```

I am able to reach my URL.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Permission issue on what?

Comment: a workaround is to import your certificate in NSS database, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773806/nss-client-certificate-not-found-nickname-not-specified
I searched for another solution before you, but haven't found it. If you do, please post it

Answer (score 31):

I've gone through the same problem, and found a solution finally, maybe it can help you.

The failure was due to the private key in [PKCS#8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5208) format:

- a PKCS#8 private key starts with
  `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----` header
  or
  `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` header

  With this key `curl` + `openssl` will works, but `curl` + `nss` +  `libnsspem.so` wouldn't.
- with a RSA private key which starts with
  `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` header

  both `curl` + `openssl` and `curl` + `nss` + `libnsspem.so` will work.

So use this command

```
openssl pkcs8 -in path/to/your/pkcs8/key -out path/to/rsa/key
```

to convert the PKCS#8 key to traditional RSA key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It may work in theory, I can't use this because in my use case I am not allowed to generate a new key for each key in my database, even temporary etc...
Finally I had to use wget instead... I just posted it to know the answer and to share it with people facing the same issue ;-)

Comment: For completeness, the correct parameters for curl are then: `--cert ./certificate.pem --key ./newkey.pem` where _newkey.pem_ is the new RSA copy of the key created wuth openssl.

Comment: I have the same issue, but I dont WANT to store an unencrypted key file. Isn't there a way that CURL can prompt me for the password and use the encrypted key?

Comment: @Brad Just add a passphrase to the RSA private key: `openssl rsa -des3 -in your.key -out your.encrypted.key`. `-des3` means encryption algorithm, you can use others, such as aes128, aes192.

Comment: @jfly I did - and It always give me the -8178 error reading the key - never prompts my for the password. I verified PEM formats, and tried a few different algoritms. ONLY works for unencrypted key.

Comment: @jfly I just had same problem and `openssl rsa -des3 -in your.key -out your.encrypted.key` worked for me - now curl works again and key is still encrypted.

Comment: @jfly I tried your advice and apparently the nss variant of curl on Centos accepts only keys that are unencrypted or encrypted via -des3. No other ciphers are accepted (Centos 7.4).

Comment: Apparently this is a known bug, reported in 2016. nss-pem does not support keys that use encryption other than des. -- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1369251

Answer (score 4):

If your certificate has a passphrase you should add it after the certificate name:

```
curl -k -v "https://myurl.com/" --cert ./certificate.pem:passphrase --key ./private.key
```